# ExpandableListActivity get Text

Tags: android

I have `ExpandableListActivity` with `Text` in each item.
How can I get text of clicked listitem?

Here`s how I do:

```
        groupData = application.getFirstLayer();
        String groupFrom[] = new String[] {"groupName"};
        int groupTo[] = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};

        childData = application.getSecondLayer();
        String childFrom[] = new String[] {"levelTwoCat"};
        int childTo[] = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};

        adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this,
            groupData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            groupFrom,
            groupTo,
            childData,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            childFrom,
            childTo);


public boolean onChildClick(android.widget.ExpandableListView parent,
            View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {}
```

What I have to write in `onChildClick` in order to see the text of current item?

Comment: Considering groupFrom the parent data information list, groupFrom[groupPosition] will give you the parent's string.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is by getting it directly from the view you clicked.  You haven't shown your row XML so the following code is going to be assuming that you have a LinearLayout with a TextView inside it as your row.

```
public boolean onChildClick(android.widget.ExpandableListView parent, 
        View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            TextView exptv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.yourtextview); //  Get the textview holding the text
            String yourText = exptv.getText().toString();  // Get the text from the view and put it in a string
            // use string as you need to
}
```

If the Layout is *only* a textview, you can just go directly to `String yourText = v.getText().toString();` since the View v that is passed in will be the TextView you need.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Jason Robinson in his comment, you are using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` for your child layout, since that is only a TextView, that simplifies the code you need to:

```
public boolean onChildClick(android.widget.ExpandableListView parent, 
        View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            String yourText = v.getText().toString();  // Get the text from the view and put it in a string
            // use string as you need to
}
```

Comment: he's using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` for his view, so the ID he would need to use to get the `TextView` would be `android.R.id.text1`